# Qpixmap look blurred when using opengl viewport in QGraphicsview

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have used QPixmapItem to display the images in a QGraphicsview viewport. I'm loading thousands of pixmaps at a time. So I decided to set some options to cache the pixmaps I'm loading for the images. Here's what I've done:

```
View->scene()->setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);
    View->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, false);

    QGLFormat fmt;
    fmt.setSampleBuffers(true);
    fmt.setSamples(2);
    //View->setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers)));
     View->setViewport(new QGLWidget(fmt));

    View->setOptimizationFlags(QGraphicsView::DontSavePainterState | QGraphicsView::DontAdjustForAntialiasing);
    View->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
 View->setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);

    View->setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);
```

If I don't use QGLWidget and OpenGL as viewport of QGraphicsVIew the pixmaps are looking normal, but if I use OpenGL viewport, the rendered pixmaps are looking "blurred". The "blurred" case is on the left, normal on the right.

[image] [image]

Comment: They are not blurred, there's some brightness added. Most likely your OpenGL driver settings are tweaked to see in dark places in first person shooter games :)

Comment: thx for the useful reply ..the left one is the opengl viewport how i can remove this property ..? can u please help me .. ? its in windows 7